# Most expensive DAPP (in terms of gas usage per transaction)

Tags: gas, dapp-development, dapps, gas-price

Which DAPP currently running or in development is likely to use the most gas per transaction?

Comment: This is going to change rapidly as new apps are deployed - and there are already apps that are broken and try and use more gas than is available in a single block. I'm not sure this is a question that will produce useful answers.